# How to recover iPod touch 2G stuck on green screen and Apple logo?

Tags: ipod-touch, startup

I have an iPod Touch 2G, I have been trying to switch it on for a few days but it won't. When I plug it in my laptop a green screen appears then it is stuck on the apple logo. I tried to start it in DFU mode but I see nothing at all on the screen then when I plug it in there is the Apple logo.

What steps can I do to recover from this situation?

Comment: Did you try [entering DFU from the computer](http://www.ehow.com/how_8042393_enter-dfu-mode-through-computers.html)?

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to start the ipod in DFU mode and restore it with iTunes and now it starts up again but half the screen is dead.

Answer (score -1):

it simpal , when struck log came appear just click power button for 3 sec then hold home button and relese the power button and hold home button until restore on itunes came up for restore for you press shift key and restore from itunes , provid ios file n enjoy